# Products of Vector Bundles

Tags: vector-bundles

Suppose that $E$ is a vector bundle over a compact, Hausdorff space $X$.  Then $E^n$ is a vector bundle over $X^n$.  If $D(E)$ is the disk bundle, there is a map on fibers $D(E^n)_x \rightarrow D(E)^n_x$.  Does this induce a homotopy equivalence $D(E^n)\simeq D(E)^n$?

Comment: Does it work when $E$ is trivial? If it does, surely the homotopy equivalence can be done more or less canonically, so it should glue to a homotopy equivalence for arbitrary locally trivial bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For any vector space $V$, there is a canonical (basis-independent) deformation retraction of $D(V)^n$ onto $D(V^n)$, obtained by moving directly inwards along a line through the origin.  Performing this on each fiber, we obtain a deformation retraction of $D(E)^n$ onto $D(E^n)$.